# Error code "Subquery returned more than 1 value [...]"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to copy rows from table 1 in a new table 3 (that I created) where ID from table 1 doesn't exists in table 2 (even if some rows are identical) and where at least one of my 3 keys in table 1 are not null

I am using *"NOT IN"* but still it returns the Following error code :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO table_3
SELECT ID, Key_1, Key_2, Key_3
FROM table_1
WHERE (SELECT ID FROM table_1) NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table_2)
AND (Key_1 IS NOT NULL) OR (Key_2 IS NOT NULL) OR (Key_3 IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This `WHERE (SELECT ID FROM table_1) NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table_2)` should most likely read `WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table_2)` - you don't need to select it again when that is the base table of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would discourage you from using `NOT IN`, using `NOT EXISTS` instead.  `NOT IN` will filter out ALL rows if ANY values in the subquery are `NULL`.

In addition, you should list the columns being inserted.

So:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (ID, Key_1, Key_2, Key3)
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Key_1, t1.Key_2, t1.Key_3
    FROM table_1 t1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM table_2 t2
                      WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                     ) AND
         (t1.Key_1 IS NOT NULL) OR
         (t1.Key_2 IS NOT NULL) OR
         (t1.Key_3 IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the ID from table_1 for comparision in the NOT in condition.

I also suggest you reference the columns by alias and also place the OR conditions in a proper bracket.

Eg:

```
INSERT 
  INTO table_3
SELECT a.ID,a.Key_1,a.Key_2,a.Key_3 
  FROM table_1 a
 WHERE a.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table_2)
   AND( (a.Key_1 IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (a.Key_2 IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (a.Key_3 IS NOT NULL)
       )
```